# How can I use MS COCO test-dev dataset for instance segmentation?

Tags: mscoco

Now I'm reproducing the Mask R-CNN(Instance segmentation task.)

I can't figure out how to use the MS COCO test dataset.

There exists 'instances_train2014', 'instances_val2014' which have specific
annotations.

But in testing data, there are only image_id, image_url, image height and width. 
I couldn't figure out how to use it at all.

Could anyone figure this out? :( 
Sorry for terrible English

Answer (score 9):

The test data is just that, test data. They did not release annotations for it. Instead, you train on the train/val datasets and submit results for the test data to the evaluation server. This ensures a fair comparison between different methods.

Answer (score 1):

So could you tell me how Researcher evaluate mAP of a model, like ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco have COCO mAP[^1] = 21(according to [This](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md))? Did they calculate on COCO validation set instead of COCO Test set and record the mAP number?

Comment: See here: https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/issues/2145 - it can't be done locally, but check out CodaLab.

Comment: This didn't answer my question. Did Researcher calculate mAP[^1]  on COCO validation set instead of  COCO Test set, or they calculate mAP[^1]  on COCO Test set using CodaLab?

Comment: They calculated mAP on COCO validation set. COCO2014 minival but different split. Can be referred to here: [^1]: See MSCOCO evaluation protocol. The COCO mAP numbers here are evaluated on COCO 14 minival set (note that our split is different from COCO 17 Val). A full list of image ids used in our split could be fould here.